# Base class remain the same if Base points to another

Tags: python, class, super

Code:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Base created"


class ChildB(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChildB, self).__init__()

Base = ChildB
Base()
```

When I do `Base = ChildB`, Base, in the global frame, points to `ChildB` which extends the previous `Base`. Since python is a dynamically-typed language, so I assume the hierarchical relationship will change. And MRO that super reference will be `ChildB > Base(ChildB) > ChildB > Base(ChildB) ....`

But the result tell the truth that ChildB still extends original Base.
Why???

Comment: it is unclear what actually you are trying to do?

Comment: You may find this article useful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. Also see [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) for a brief summary with nice diagrams.

Comment: @xiº It's my question about the answer from S C to [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods

](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse the class whose *name* is `Base` with the Python *variable* `Base` that originally referred to it.

```
>>> class Base(object): pass
...
>>> class ChildBase(Base): pass
...
>>> Base = ChildBase
>>> Base.__name__
'ChildBase'
```

When `ChildBase` is defined, the name `Base` is still bound to the class `Base`, so that is the parent class of `ChildBase`, regardless of what the name `Base` is subsequently bound to.

A class statement is like `class Base(object): pass` is equivalent to a call to `type`:

```
Base = type('Base', (object,), {})
```

The identifier `Base` is used both for the name of the class and the variable bound to the resulting object.